# Send multiple email address using phpmailer function

Tags: php, email, while-loop, smtp

I have a problem sending multiple email addresses functions. If I send a single email address, I can work. If I send multiple emails to the receiver, they cannot receive my message. I am using the PHPMailer function to do the email function with XAMPP. I am using the PHP array function to put the receiver's address in the array and use the while function to loop the receiver address to send it.

Below is my coding:

```html
$address = array('st9overfindsolution@gmail','st7overfindsolution@gmail');
require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();                                
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';     
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->Port = 465;                              
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';              
$mail->Password = '1233aqqq';                   
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                      
$mail->From = $_POST["email"];                  
$mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];               

$mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);  
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                           
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                            
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];             
$mail->Body = $_POST["message"];                

while(list ($key, $val) = each($address)){
$mail->AddAddress($val);        
}
```

`What I've tried?`

1.I put all receiver email addresses in the array `$address = array('st9overfindsolution@gmail','st7overfindsolution@gmail');` and use below `while` function code, but cannot work.

2.If send single email address without using `while` function, just can work, like below coding:

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have created new function named "sendmyemail" and inserted the code inside this function, so you can sent multiple emails by calling this function with email address.

```php
<?php

/**
 * This example shows sending a message using a local sendmail binary.
 */

//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

function sendmyemail($whotoEmail){
  //Create a new PHPMailer instance
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  //Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
  $mail->isSendmail();
  //Set who the message is to be sent from
  $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
  //Set who the message is to be sent to
  $mail->addAddress($whotoEmail);
  //Set the subject line
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';
  //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to           
  embedded,
  //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
  $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
  //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
  //Attach an image file
  $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

  //send the message, check for errors
  if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo 'Message sent to '.$whotoEmail.'!';
  }
}
sendmyemail('abcduser@gmail.com');
sendmyemail('efguser@gmail.com');
sendmyemail('hijkuser@gmail.com');
sendmyemail('lmnouser@gmail.com');
```

Comment: so your function no need to put in the array right?

Comment: yea no need array

Comment: $address = ""'st9overfindsolution@gmail','st7overfindsolution@gmail'"";
sendmyemail($address );
can do like this?

Comment: because $address variable data is grabbed from database.